# Common Access Card (CAC) not working on RHEL 7 with Firefox 59.0.3

Tags: linux, firefox, certificate, smartcard

I have a Common Access Card and I'd like to use my CAC on my notebook with RHEL 7.4 and FireFox 59.0.3 installed.

I did a yum install on pcsc-lite, pcsc-lite-ccid, pcsc-lite-ccid, and pcsc-tools.

running lsusb returns:

us 001 Device 005: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader

I've installed the following certs:

DOD CA-31.cer        DOD ID CA-33.cer     DOD ID SW CA-45.cer
DOD CA-32.cer        DOD ID CA-34.cer     DOD ID SW CA-46.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-31.cer  DOD ID CA-39.cer     DOD ID SW CA-47.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-32.cer  DOD ID CA-40.cer     DOD ID SW CA-48.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-33.cer  DOD ID CA-41.cer     DoDRoot2.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-34.cer  DOD ID CA-42.cer     DoDRoot3.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-39.cer  DOD ID CA-43.cer     DoDRoot4.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-40.cer  DOD ID CA-44.cer     DoDRoot5.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-41.cer  DOD ID CA-49.cer     DOD SW CA-53.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-42.cer  DOD ID CA-50.cer     DOD SW CA-54.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-43.cer  DOD ID CA-51.cer     DOD SW CA-55.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-44.cer  DOD ID CA-52.cer     DOD SW CA-56.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-49.cer  DOD ID SW CA-35.cer  DOD SW CA-57.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-50.cer  DOD ID SW CA-36.cer  DOD SW CA-58.cer
DOD EMAIL CA-51.cer  DOD ID SW CA-37.cer  DoD_PKE_CA_chain.pem                       InstallRoot_PKCS7_v3.16.1A.sha1 InstallRoot_PKCS7_v3.16.1A.der.p7b         InstallRoot_PKCS7_v3.16.1A.sha256 InstallRoot_PKCS7_v3.16.1A.pem.p7b
InstallRoot_PKCS7_v3.16.1A.pem-signed.p7b

I went into FF and went to Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> Security Devices and loaded with Coolkey module by pointing the browser to /usr/lib64/pkcs11/libcoolkeypk11.so

When I insert my CAC and click the Log In button from the Device Manager in FF, it asks me for my PIN, and after entering my PIN, it recognizes me.

However when I browse to a URL which requires CAC login, the webpage request eventually times out without doing anything.

How can I get my CAC to work with webpages?  All it's doing presently is timing out.

Comment: Firefox on Windows requires you use a software client like ActivClient, in order to read the certificate on the card, in order to use it when connected to a website.  It appears based on my limited research, that is the case on Linux also, so have you tried doing that?  There is an entire website dedicated to this subject, of using your CAC at home, even has a page on [Linux](https://militarycac.com/linux.htm).

Comment: @Ramhound.  I'm running on Linux.  Not windows.  I have not installed ActiveClient on my Linux host, now owned by HID, because it's not FOSS.  On https://iase.disa.mil/pki-pke/getting_started/Pages/linux-firefox.aspx, DISA says to use Coolkey instead.  Taht's what I have done so far.  I can see the certs from my CAC on the local host so at least I have some configuration/installation of libs, correct.  I cannot get my CAC to work with webpages though.

Comment: > even has a page on Linux... I have seen that page.  It's full of outdated material and links which generate 404 errors.  Despite the URL and some of the format, it's NOT an official page.  That's why after trying to use it and being disappointed, I went to disa.mil.

Comment: I am more than aware it was unofficial.  I could not bring up the page, but I have read other pages on the website, and it's a good source of information.  I will investigate this issue, when I get a chance, over the weekend.

Comment: Do you really need Coolkey? Doesn't OpenSC (opensc-pkcs11.so) already have CAC support without any additional software?

Comment: @grawity I tried Coolkey at first because that's what's on DISA's page.  I  tried OpenSC since then too.  With both products< i get exactly the same behavior.  Thanks though.